# Crash on Fragment change in RecyclerView. I can't find a solution

Tags: android

When i try to change fragment on clickevent, app crash. Im new on Android :). I am trying to change fragment when I click on a menu created in a RecyclerActivity. verything works fine except when I try to change one fragment to another. I tried from the adapter to change the fragment and in a thousand ways but I can't find any possible solution.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Item> mData;
    MenuAdapter adapter;

    public static final int DASHBOARD_CODE = 0;
    public static final int SETTINGS_CODE = 1;
    public static final int CONTACT_CODE = 2;
    public static final int DONATE_CODE = 3;
    public static final int EXIT_CODE = 4;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvMenu);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mData = new ArrayList<>();

        mData.add(new Item(R.drawable.menu_home, DASHBOARD_CODE, "Dashboard Fragment"));
        mData.add(new Item(R.drawable.menu_settings, SETTINGS_CODE, "Dashboard Fragment"));
        mData.add(new Item(R.drawable.menu_contact, CONTACT_CODE, "Dashboard Fragment"));
        mData.add(new Item(R.drawable.menu_donate, DONATE_CODE, "Dashboard Fragment"));
        mData.add(new Item(R.drawable.menu_exit, EXIT_CODE, "Dashboard Fragment"));

        adapter = new MenuAdapter(this, mData);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        dashboard_fragment dashboardFrag = new dashboard_fragment();
        ajustes_fragment ajustes_fragment = new ajustes_fragment();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, dashboardFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                        Fragment newFragment = new ajustes_fragment();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                    }

                    @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "asd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }})
        );

    }

}
```

```
public class MenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.MenuViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    List<Item> mData;
    int posicion_seleccionada;

    public MenuAdapter(Context mContext, List<Item> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent,false);
        return new MenuViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getIcon());
        holder.imgIcon.setBackgroundColor(posicion_seleccionada == position ? Color.parseColor("#fff1f1f1") :Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imgIcon;


        public MenuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_icon);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(posicion_seleccionada==2) {
                        Intent intent;

                    }
                    notifyItemChanged(posicion_seleccionada);
                    posicion_seleccionada= getAdapterPosition();
                    notifyItemChanged(posicion_seleccionada);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Add the stack trace of the crash

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and i solve it like this: (you didn't add details/log about the crash so i hope my solution will help, plz next time add more information)

Change **onCreateViewHolder** method to( I change the variables to fits yours) :

```
public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent,false);
    MenuViewHolder holder = new MenuViewHolder(v);

    v.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {

        Fragment newFragment = new ajustes_fragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = ((FragmentActivity)parent.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

    });
    return holder;
}
```

Comment: I already solved the problem, it was the fault of not removing code that was automatically generated in the fragment, also thank you very much for the response and sorry for not closing.